# CI active record, escapes & order_by datetime column

Tags: sql, codeigniter, datetime, activerecord, sql-order-by

I've noticed that when ordering by a datetime column in CI with active record, it's treating the column as a string, or int.

Example:

```
$this->db->limit(12);
    $this->db->where('subscribed',1);   
    $this->db->join('profiles','profiles.user_id=users.id');
    $this->db->where('active',1);
    $this->db->select('users.thumbUpload,users.vanity_url');
    $this->db->select('users.created_on as time');
    $this->db->order_by('time');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
```

This is where users.created_on is a datetime field. Firstly, is it because active record is rendering `time` escaped, or is it something else? And if it is, can I prevent the escaping on order_by somehow?

Also, stackoverflow, please stop autocorrecting 'datetime' to 'date time'. It's annoying.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set second argument as false, function wont check and escape string. Try this

```
$this->db->select('users.created_on as time', FALSE);
```

Or for you query use

```
$this->db->order_by('users.created_on', 'DESC'); //or ASC
```

And for complex queries

```
$this->db->query("query");
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the order_by that doesn't seem to able to set as false. Is there a way around that, without resorting to listing the whole thing out in db->query('foo')?

Comment: @MichaelWatson yes its. For complex queries which you cant use active record tips, call with only `db->query('foo')`

Comment: Also try `db->order_by(users.created_on)`

Comment: Hmmm, stipulating the table as you suggested doesn't resolve the issue. I'll lay it out in a db->query(). Shame, and a little strange order_by() doesn't allow skipping escaping, as I'm sure people order_by datetime quite often.

Comment: @MichaelWatson are you sure its not working ? maybe you want `DESC` order ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the signature of the method in core files of CI (currently 2.2), it does not have any option to allow to choose whether or not to escape.

```
// The original prototype of the order_by()
public function order_by($orderby, $direction = '') {
    // Definition
}
```

As you see there is not argument as `$escape = true` in the argument list. One way to do so is to **hack this core file** (*I normally do not suggest it, since if you upgrade CI to a newer version later, then these changes will be lost, but if you do not intend to do so, it is OK to use it*).

To do so, first change the prototype as:

```
public function order_by($orderby, $direction = '', $escape = true) {
    // Definition
}
```

And then check the conditions in the following parts of definition:

```
// Line 842
if($escape){
    $part = $this->_protect_identifiers(trim($part));
}else {
    $part = trim($part);
}

// Line 856
if($escape){
    $orderby = $this->_protect_identifiers($orderby);
}
```

When you call it, to prevent the escaping:

```
$this->db->order_by($ORDERBY_CLAUSE, null, false);
```